# Creating dictionaries during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script supporting users in FE analysis.
During the runtime of the script I get a list of FEA entities like this

```
Ents=['BAR','SHELL','BEAM']
```

I have to create a dictionary for each item in the list to collect and store the correct values from another source and the number of possible FEA entities is long and may change if a new entity is introduced.

Is there a way to create a dictionary "dynamically during the runtime" (I have no better idea to describe my request) like

```
for item in Ents:
    item+'_dict' = dict()
```

So as a result I get 3 dicts for the example above: BAR_dict, SHELL_dict and BEAM_dict

And for

```
Ents = ['TRUSS','WELD','CONNECTOR']
```

I get a dict named TRUSS_dict, WELD_dict and CONNECTOR_dict

Comment: Why not store all dicts in a "super-dict", like `dicts = dict(); dicts[item+'_dict'] = dict()`?

Comment: You may also have a dict of dict using dict comprenhension: `Ents_dict = {e: {} for e in Ents}`

Comment: Using dynamic variables is generally considered an anti-pattern in Python. Rather, you should use some sort of *container*. The type you choose depend son your needs. In this case, you seem to want to access your data by using a *string*, so *another* dict is a natural choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
EntDicts = {}
for Ent in Ents:
    EntDicts[Ent] = {}
```

Then use `EntDicts` at will...